# error when fetching data from api and try to display in scrollable row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I try to display images in scrollable row but the app runs but nothing is displayed
when i log at the game list and the game card and the main screen there is data but nothing is showned

The code of the game list

```
@Composable
fun GameList(
    gameList: List<Result>,
    //navController: NavController,
    it:PaddingValues
){
    Box {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(50.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(it)
        ) {
            for (games in gameList) {
                //Log.d(TAG,games.background_image)
                GameCard(game = games)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code of the game card

```
@Composable
fun GameCard(
    game:Result,
    //onClick:() -> Unit
){
    Card(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(8.dp)) {
                game.background_image.let { url ->
                    val image = loadPicture(url = url,
                        defaultImage = DEFAULT_Game_IMAGE).value
                    image?.let {img ->
                        Image(bitmap = img.asImageBitmap(),
                            contentDescription = "gameImage",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(100.dp)
                                .height(100.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

and at the main screen

```
val games = viewModel.games.value
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopBar(navController = navController) }
    ) { it ->
        //Log.d(TAG,"games in screen : $games")
            GameList(gameList = games, it = it)
    }
```

what i tried to do is to display it in a scrollable column to make sure the data is displayed correctly and it did but not in the scrollable row

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove fixed width from `Row()`:

```
Box {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(50.dp)
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(it)
        ) {
            for (games in gameList) {
                //Log.d(TAG,games.background_image)
                GameCard(game = games)
            }
        }
    }
```

And apply that width to `GameCard` directly instead of `fillMaxSize()`:

```
@Composable
fun GameCard(
    game:Result,
    //onClick:() -> Unit
){
    Card(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(50.dp)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .padding(10.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(8.dp)) {
                game.background_image.let { url ->
                    val image = loadPicture(url = url,
                        defaultImage = DEFAULT_Game_IMAGE).value
                    image?.let {img ->
                        Image(bitmap = img.asImageBitmap(),
                            contentDescription = "gameImage",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(100.dp) // This is of no use as parent's max size is 50.dp!
                                .height(100.dp),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Or alternatively, you can shift scroll modifier to `Box()` which is parent of `Row()` composable:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(50.dp)
                .height(50.dp)
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(it)
        ) {
            for (games in gameList) {
                //Log.d(TAG,games.background_image)
                GameCard(game = games)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Reason**: Since you apply fixed width to `Row()`, then only that much part will be scrollable - not full part. Also, your UI will be limited to 50.dp only, so GameCard won't look exactly as you want.